# In Dart - is there a similar package to python's inspect module?

Tags: dart, flutter

When logging in python, I use:

```
    (filepathname, line_number,
     name, lines, index) = inspect.getframeinfo(sys._getframe(2))

    code_info_str = ": {} - {} - {} : ".format(os.path.basename(filepathname), line_number, name)
```

Is there something similar in Dart?  (thank you).

Comment: What is the problem? What are you trying to accomplish? What is frameinfo?

Comment: I have a Dart class called logging.  When I call it's print statement, I want to display the method name where the logging was called.  In python, I can also print the line number (which is also helpful). This type of info is in the frameinfo.

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:logging/logging.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'package:stack_trace/stack_trace.dart';

Logger log;

void initLogger({@required String package, String tag}) {
  assert(package != null);

  Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
  Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord rec) {
    final List<Frame> frames = Trace.current().frames;
    final Frame f = frames.skip(1).firstWhere((Frame f) => f.package == package, orElse: () => frames.first);
    print('${rec.level.name}/${rec.loggerName}: ${f.member} (${f.library}:${f.line}): ${rec.message}');
  });

  log = Logger(tag?.toUpperCase() ?? package.toUpperCase());
}

initLogger(package: '<app>', tag: '<tag>');

// <app> is where you put the name of your app, like 'my_taxi_app'
// you need to put the right app name or it will not work
```

from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2200#issuecomment-395970766).

You need to call `initLogger` just one time, maybe in `main.dart`.

At the top of each source file you want to add logging, you add

`var log = Logger('my_specific_file_name');` and then you call log with

`log.info('something happened!');`

Comment: I tried this.  The stack frame that gets printed out is for the initLogger routine (in other words, the info tells me the print statement is on line 10 within the initLogger function).  doing a `frames.forEach((f) => print(f));` shows after many frames, i can eventually grok to the line..but it isn't always going to be the same place since the stack is going through the logging package, etc.

Comment: did you set `package` parameter to the name of your app?

Comment: yah.  but the package string adds package::  this filtering worked for me: `    final Frame f = frames.skip(0).firstWhere((Frame f) => f.library.toLowerCase().contains(rec.loggerName.toLowerCase())  
     && f != frames.first);`

Comment: Then i simplified the output slightly to `    print(
        '${rec.level.name}: ${f.member} (${f.library}:${f.line}): ${rec.message}');
  });`

Answer (score 1):

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.1/dart-core/StackTrace/current.html would allow to get the information, but I think you would need to extract it yourself. I don't think there is a ready-to-use package for your use case.

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stack_trace seems to make stack traces easier to work with, but I didn't use this package myself yet.